# Image in tkinter window by clicking on button

Tags: python, image, canvas, window, tkinter

I need help about this program, this program should open image in new tkinter window by clicking on button, but it doesn't it just opens new window without image.
Where is the problem?

Using: python 3.3 and tkinter

This is program:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *


def button1():
    novi = Toplevel()
    canvas = Canvas(novi, width = 300, height = 200)
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'image.gif')
    canvas.create_image(50, 10, visual = gif1, anchor = NW)


mGui = Tk()
button1 = Button(mGui,text ='Sklop',command = button1, height=5, width=20).pack()

mGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`create_image` needs a `image` argument, not `visual` to use the image, so instead of `visual = gif1`, you need `image = gif1`. The next problem is that you need to store the `gif1` reference somewhere or else it'll get garbage collected and tkinter won't be able to use it anymore.

So something like this:

```
import sys
from tkinter import * #or Tkinter if you're on Python2.7

def button1():
    novi = Toplevel()
    canvas = Canvas(novi, width = 300, height = 200)
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'image.gif')
                                #image not visual
    canvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
    #assigned the gif1 to the canvas object
    canvas.gif1 = gif1


mGui = Tk()
button1 = Button(mGui,text ='Sklop',command = button1, height=5, width=20).pack()

mGui.mainloop()
```

It's also probably not a good idea to name your `Button` the same name as the function `button1`, that'll just cause confusion later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Creater window")

def Img():
    r = Toplevel()
    r.title("My image")

    canvas = Canvas(r, height=600, width=600)
    canvas.pack()
    my_image = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python34\\Lib\idlelib\\Icons\\Baba.gif', master= root)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=my_image)
    r.mainloop()

btn = Button(root, text = "Click Here to see creator Image", command = Img)
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes