# Tkinter GUI, Open File .. Button and BMP images .. Error on showing a selected file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I'm doing a program that is written in Python and what it should do is Displaying a GUI with a button there to open a image file, and then you'll should be able to see those image, pan and zoom on them.

Heres my code so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os, tkFileDialog


button_flag = True

def click():
    global button_flag
    if button_flag:
        button1.config(bg="white")
        button_flag = False
    else:
        button1.config(bg="green")
        button_flag = True

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

image1 = Image.open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())

button1 = tk.Button(frame1, compound=tk.TOP, width=155, height=55, image=image1, text="optional tet", bg='green', command=click)
button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

button1.image = image1

root.mainloop()
```

But when I choose the image it gets me an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\test3", line 24, in <module>
button1 = tk.Button(frame1, compound=tk.TOP, width=155, height=55, image=image1, text="optional tet", bg='green', command=click)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2106, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2036, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: image "<PIL.BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=P size=1086x1580 at 0x317A648>" doesn't exist
```

Other thing is that I can't configure a button to when clicked open an image (from a `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` ) and then showing the full image, not just a zoomed version fitted to the gui size.

I've searched those but did ***not*** really help:

- [Adding image to Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380901/adding-image-to-tkinter),
- [Display jpg images in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356255/display-jpg-images-in-python),
- [Image in tkinter window by clicking on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999661/image-in-tkinter-window-by-clicking-on-button)

Comment: It looks like `image1` is an image object, but the `tk.Button` constructor is expecting the path to an image so it's trying to find the string representation of the image file on disk (and failing).

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: @Trengot: you are incorrect. The `tk.Button` command requires an image object, not the path to a file.

Comment: @BryanOakley, fair enough. I was just going by the error message. If I was sure I'd have made it an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button command requires an instance of the PhotoImage class. It cannot directly display a PIL object. Change your code to be this:

```
pil_image = Image.open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename())
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
```

Comment: This actually puts the image in the button, and I want to press the button to open and another on to display it. Do I use the image show?

Comment: @santoznma: I don't understand the question. Your original code was attempting to put an image in a button, so that's what my example shows. Regardless, the answer to your problem is that you can't directly display a PIL image, you must convert it to a PhotoImage.

Comment: That worked actually (putting the image in the button). After you convert it to Photoimage, how do you display it?

Comment: @santoznma: put it in a label, a button, or embed it in a canvas or text widget.